# Can't build customise Slack notifications

Tags: sh, slack, rundeck

After much research, I discovered this **.sh** script, which allows me to send a very simple personalized notification to a Slack channel (I failed to send it to a particular member).
The problem, which I am facing, is that of formatting the message of the notification. The tags offered on the Slack site to format the notification do not work correctly (that I do not know how to use them!).
The notification must be built "from scratch" at the end of each execution of the Rundeck job.
Rundeck's "*On Failure*" and "*On Success*" notifications are not suitable for users.

This the sh script :

```
#!/bin/bash
​#Usage: slackpost <channel> <message>
slackhost="https://hooks.slack.com/services"
token="XXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
slack_username="Someone-who-loves-you"
slack_icon="smile"​
channel=$1
if [[ $channel == "" ]]
then
    echo "No channel specified"
    exit 1
fi
text="$2"

if [[ $text == "" ]]
then
    echo "No text specified"
    exit 1
fi
escapedText=$(echo $text | sed 's/"/\"/g' | sed "s/'/\'/g" )
json="{\"channel\": \"#$channel\", \"username\":\"${slack_username}\", \"icon_emoji\":\":${slack_icon}:\",  \"text\": \"$escapedText\"}"
curl -s -d "payload=$json" "$slackhost/$token"
```

The variable $text is filled with the content of a .txt file (myFileText):

myFileText content is as follows:

```
text="",
{
    blocks=[
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": "Hello world! <@UNVD64N02> :tada: \n\n - a \n-b"
            }
        }
    ]
}
{
    "blocks": [
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": "Hello, Assistant to the Regional Manager John Doe! *Martin Scott* wants to know where you'd like to take the Paper Company investors to dinner tonight.\n\n *Please select a restaurant:*"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The .sh script is run as follows:

```
sh slack_post.sh "channel-receiving-the-notification" "$(< myFileText)"
```

As result I have :

```
invalid_payload
```

Any idea could be helpful.

Comment: You probably need to escape the quotes in the myFileText file

Comment: Following the Raman comment, this would be useful in your case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51333632/10426011

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. It's now a little better. Payload is Ok. But I still have a such as this result : 
{
blocks:[
{
type: section,
text: {
type: mrkdwn,
text: Hello world! @C01S0SF5V19 :tada:
- a
-b
} ...
The formatting of blocks and tags is not operational.